# Decomposition of auto correlated variable

Tags: regression, correlation, random-variable, autocorrelation, cross-correlation

Can the sum of two (or more) random variables with zero auto-correlations and zero cross-correlations yield a random variable that has non zero auto-correlation?

Comment: Note: If this question is for an homework, a tag "self-study" should be added.

Comment: Since you refer to "auto-correlations," are you perhaps using "random variables" in the sense of *stochastic processes?*  If not, could you please explain what you mean by "auto-correlation" of a random variable?

Comment: I meant to use stochastic process. Autocorrelations would be the covariance between the variable and its lags.

Answer (score 3):

Save a mistake or a misunderstanding, no.

Let $A_t$ and $B_t$ be two variables.

For all $t \neq s$: $cov(A_t,A_s)=0$ (zero auto-correlation)

For all $t \neq s$: $cov(B_t,B_s)=0$ (zero auto-correlation)

For all $t$, $s$: $cov(A_t,B_s)=0$. (zero cross-correlation)

Then:
$cov(A_t+B_t,A_s+B_s) = cov(A_t,A_s) + cov(B_t,B_s) + cov(A_t,B_s) + cov(B_t,A_s) = 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 0$